# How to minimize the output window in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans

I have the output window that takes the whole page but I want just want it to be at the bottom. How can I do please (it's increasingly making me angry) ?[image]

Comment: Drag it into the lower area (where the "Git" window icon is)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Click on the "Output" field with the left mouse button, hold and drag down. After that, release the button.